# how to check if a double ends in .33

Tags: swift, double

I am writing in swift and I need to carry out code similar to this `if myDouble ends in .33 { "carry out code"}`
How do I run a check on the decimal value of my number while ignoring the whole numbers?
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you need to round it first?  1/3 wouldn't end in .33, it actually never ends theoretically..

Comment: this number is user defined from a text field so I need to add 0.01 to the number if they choose a number ending in .33 before I use the number in the rest of my calculations

Comment: Yea, your basic logic is flawed... What if the double "ends" in .330000000001 are you saying you wouldn't want to run the code in question? Because frankly, a double will never end in *exactly* .33. The structure of a Double won't allow it.

Comment: Either convert it to a string, separate it at the "." and examine the decimal string part. Or this may help if you don't want to use Strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396301/getting-the-decimal-part-of-a-double-in-swift

Comment: Do something like: `if fabs(fabs(myDouble) - floor(fabs(myDouble)) - 0.33) < 0.001`.  Adjust `0.001` to whatever accuracy you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let myDouble = 10.0/3  //  3.333333333333333

if String(format: "%.2f", myDouble).hasSuffix(".33") {
    print(true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Short sharp and affective. Exactly what I was hoping to use

Answer (score 0):

Just do `abs(myDouble - floor(myDouble))`,  that will get your decimal value.  then do any rounding or formatting needed to handle infinite 3's or what not

Make sure you import Foundation, it's required to use floor:
`import Foundation`

Answer (score 0):

```
let double = 4.3391762
let newDouble = String(format: "%.03f", double)
let thirtyThree = abs(Double(newDouble)! - floor(Double(double))) * 100

floor(thirtyThree)
```

Probably could be refactored but there's one way.