# How to truncate decimals to x places in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, double, decimal

I have a really long decimal number (say `17.9384693864596069567`) and I want to truncate the decimal to a few decimal places (so I want the output to be `17.9384`). I do **not** want to round the number to `17.9385`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift

Comment: Either solution below is wholly effective.

Comment: Sure, was just showing you another one :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can tidy this up even more by making it an extension of `Double`:

```swift
extension Double {
    func truncate(places : Int)-> Double {
        return Double(floor(pow(10.0, Double(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Double(places)))
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```swift
var num = 1.23456789
// return the number truncated to 2 places
print(num.truncate(places: 2))

// return the number truncated to 6 places
print(num.truncate(places: 6))
```

Comment: I like it! So organized and it actually makes sense when you use it :).

Comment: glad you like it - it's the first extension I have ever written, so we have both learned something today :-)

Comment: This doesn't work on numbers below 1 :(
If you use `0.23456789.truncate(2)` you'll get `0.23000000000000001`

Comment: What about this value : "2315385.01" , it gives 2315385, which is wrong

Comment: Jeroen Bakker - I don't know why you think that, because it does return 0.23  @Samarth Kejriwal - that is odd.  It doesn't do that for numbers on either side of your magic number

Comment: @Russell I want the result of "2315385.01" as "2315385.01" after truncating, but the results come out to be 2315385. Any edit in the answer?

Answer (score 13):

You can keep it simple with:

```
String(format: "%.0f", ratio*100)
```

Where 0 is the amount of decimals you want to allow. In this case zero. Ratio is a double like: 0.5556633.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the right answer if you want to consume the double as a string.

Comment: Though I would simply go like so: `String(format: "%.2f", 0.123` to generate a string like so: `"0.12"`

Answer (score 10):

I figured this one out.

Just floor (round down) the number, with some fancy tricks.

```
let x = 1.23556789
let y = Double(floor(10000*x)/10000) // leaves on first four decimal places
let z = Double(floor(1000*x)/1000) // leaves on first three decimal places
print(y) // 1.2355
print(z) // 1.235
```

So, multiply by 1 and the number of 0s being the decimal places you want, floor that, and divide it by what you multiplied it by. And voila.

Answer (score 6):

```
extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func roundToPlaces(_ places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
    func cutOffDecimalsAfter(_ places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self*divisor).rounded(.towardZero) / divisor
    }
}

let a:Double = 1.228923598

print(a.roundToPlaces(2)) // 1.23
print(a.cutOffDecimalsAfter(2)) // 1.22
```

Answer (score 5):

The code for specific digits after decimals is:

```
let number = 17.9384693864596069567;
let merichle = Float(String(format: "%.1f", (number * 10000)).dropLast(2))!/10000

//merichle = 17.9384
```

And ultimately, your number gets truncate without round...

Comment: This looks like it'll work just fine if you're looking for a String as output instead of a Double.

Comment: @owlswipe
if you want double number, you may use this code:
`Double(String(format: "%.2f", b))`

Comment: Good call, that way looks fine to me :)

Comment: @RamazanKarami String(format: "%.2f", b) will round a double, not truncate it.

Comment: @George
Yes, you're right. The answer was corrected by a new edit without roundthe number. Thanks for your follow up

Comment: `let number = 1.99999999` and your code will return `merichle = 2`.

Answer (score 4):

In swift 5 truncation to decimal can also be done by creating extension to decimal

```
extension Decimal {
  func truncation(by digit: Int) -> Decimal {
    var initialDecimal = self
    var roundedDecimal = Decimal()
    NSDecimalRound(&roundedDecimal, &initialDecimal, digit, .plain)
    return roundedDecimal
  }
```

use case for decimal value

```
value = Decimal(2.56430).truncation(by:2)
```

value = 2.560000 (after truncation)

Comment: I like the idea behind this, but there is a bug. This actually rounds, it does not truncate. The `.plain` causes NSDecimalRound to round up or down. Replace it with `.down` to always round down, which will give it the behavior of truncating.

Comment: @stef this is relative. If the number is negative you would have to use .up. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865)

Answer (score 3):

### Drag/Drop Solution, IOS, Swift 4

Copy this code into your application...

```
import Foundation

func truncateDigitsAfterDecimal(number: Double, afterDecimalDigits: Int) -> Double {
   if afterDecimalDigits < 1 || afterDecimalDigits > 512 {return 0.0}
   return Double(String(format: "%.\(afterDecimalDigits)f", number))!
}
```

Then you can call this function like:

```
truncateDigitsAfterDecimal(number: 45.123456789, afterDecimalDigits: 3)
```

Will produce the following:

```
45.123
```

Comment: this will round it, not truncate

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI:
If you are truncating to format output in a view, but not computation, SwiftUI contains a convenient way to use C format specifiers as part of the signature for Text().

```
import SwiftUI

let myDouble = 17.93846938645960695
Text("\(myDouble, specifier: "%.2f")")
///Device display: 17.94
```

Above code will output the contents of Double directly to the View, rounded correctly to the hundredth place, but preserve the value of the Double for further calculations.

If as a user of SwiftUI you are unfamiliar with the C language format specifiers, this link contains helpful information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: Your solution is rounding decimal number... Read the question one more time.

Answer (score 1):

**Way 1:** If you don't want to create any new function for this, you can do it this way for getting the rounded value directly.

```
var roundedValue = (decimalValue * pow(10.0, Double(numberOfPlaces))).rounded())/pow(10.0, Double(numberOfPlaces)
```

Example:

```
var numberOfPlaces = 2
var decimalValue = 13312.2423423523523

print("\(((decimalValue * pow(10.0, Double(numberOfPlaces))).rounded())/pow(10.0, Double(numberOfPlaces)))")
```

Result: 13312.24

---

---

**Way 2:** if you just want to print, you may use:

```
print(String(format: "%.\(numberOfPlaces)f",decimalValue))
```

Example

```
var numberOfPlaces = 4
var decimalValue = 13312.2423423523523

print(String(format: "%.\(numberOfPlaces)f",decimalValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Swift 5.2

I have looked a lot of answers and I always had conversion issues when truncating. According to my maths knowledge, by truncating I understand that if I have 3.1239 and I want 3 decimals then I will have 3.123 with no rounding (!= 3.1234).

Maybe, because of the nature of the process, I was always successful with Doubles but always had issues with Floats.

My approach is to create an extension of BinaryFloatingPoint so I can reuse it for Float, CGFLoat, Double ...

The following extension gets a BinaryFloatingPoint and can return the String or the BinaryFloatingPoint values with a numberOfDecimals given and it handles different type of cases:

```
extension Numeric where Self: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    
    /// Retruns the string value of the BinaryFloatingPoint. The initiaiser
    var toString: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
    
    /// Returns the number of decimals. It will be always greater than 0
    var numberOfDecimals: Int {
        return toString.count - String(Int(self)).count - 1
    }
   
    /// Returns a Number with a certain number of decimals
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - Parameter numberOfDecimals: Number of decimals to return
    /// - Returns: BinaryFloatingPoint with number of decimals especified
    func with(numberOfDecimals: Int) -> Self {
        let stringValue = string(numberOfDecimals: numberOfDecimals)
        if self is Double {
            return Double(stringValue) as! Self
        } else {
            return Float(stringValue) as! Self
        }
    }
    
    /// Returns a string representation with a number of decimals
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - Parameter numberOfDecimals: Number of decimals to return
    /// - Returns: String with number of decimals especified
    func string(numberOfDecimals: Int) -> String {
        let selfString = toString
        let selfStringComponents = selfString.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let selfStringIntegerPart = selfStringComponents[0]
        let selfStringDecimalPart = selfStringComponents[1]
        
        if numberOfDecimals == 0 {
            return selfStringIntegerPart
        } else {
            if selfStringDecimalPart.count == numberOfDecimals {
                return [selfStringIntegerPart,
                        selfStringDecimalPart].joined(separator: ".")
            } else {
                if selfStringDecimalPart.count > numberOfDecimals {
                    return [selfStringIntegerPart,
                            String(selfStringDecimalPart.prefix(numberOfDecimals))].joined(separator: ".")
                } else {
                    let difference = numberOfDecimals - selfStringDecimalPart.count
                    let addedCharacters = [Character].init(repeating: "0", count: difference)
                    
                    return [selfStringIntegerPart,
                            selfStringDecimalPart+addedCharacters].joined(separator: ".")
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
}
```

It might look old school but all my tests are passing:

```
func test_GivenADecimalNumber_ThenAssertNumberOfDecimalsWanted() {
   //No decimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3).with(numberOfDecimals: 0), 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 0), 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 0), 3)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3).with(numberOfDecimals: 0), 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 0), 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 0), 3)
    
    
    //numberOfDecimals == totalNumberOfDecimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.00).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.00)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.09)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.01).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.01)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.999)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.991).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.991)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.00).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.00)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.09)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.01).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.01)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.999)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.991).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.991)
    
    
    //numberOfDecimals < totalNumberOfDecimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.00).with(numberOfDecimals: 1), 3.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 1), 3.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.01).with(numberOfDecimals: 1), 3.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.99)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.991).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.99)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.00).with(numberOfDecimals: 1), 3.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 1), 3.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.01).with(numberOfDecimals: 1), 3.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.99)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.991).with(numberOfDecimals: 2), 3.99)
    
    
    //numberOfDecimals > totalNumberOfDecimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.00).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.000)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.090)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.01).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.010)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 4), 3.9990)
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.991).with(numberOfDecimals: 4), 3.9910)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.00).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.000)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.090)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.01).with(numberOfDecimals: 3), 3.010)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).with(numberOfDecimals: 4), 3.9990)
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.991).with(numberOfDecimals: 4), 3.9910)
}

func test_GivenADecimal_ThenAssertStringValueWithDecimalsWanted() {
    //No decimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3).string(numberOfDecimals: 0), "3")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 0), "3")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 0), "3")
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3).string(numberOfDecimals: 0), "3")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 0), "3")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 0), "3")
    
    
    //numberOfDecimals == totalNumberOfDecimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.00).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.00")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.09")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.01).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.01")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.999")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.991).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.991")
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.00).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.00")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.09")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.01).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.01")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.999")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.991).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.991")
    
    
    //numberOfDecimals < totalNumberOfDecimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.00).string(numberOfDecimals: 1), "3.0")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 1), "3.0")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.01).string(numberOfDecimals: 1), "3.0")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.99")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.991).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.99")
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.00).string(numberOfDecimals: 1), "3.0")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 1), "3.0")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.01).string(numberOfDecimals: 1), "3.0")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.99")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.991).string(numberOfDecimals: 2), "3.99")
    
    
    //numberOfDecimals > totalNumberOfDecimals
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.00).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.000")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.090")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.01).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.010")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 4), "3.9990")
    XCTAssertEqual(Float(3.991).string(numberOfDecimals: 4), "3.9910")
    
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.00).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.000")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.09).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.090")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.01).string(numberOfDecimals: 3), "3.010")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.999).string(numberOfDecimals: 4), "3.9990")
    XCTAssertEqual(Double(3.991).string(numberOfDecimals: 4), "3.9910")
}
```

Comment: extending `Numeric` protocol and constraining it to `BinaryFloatingPoint` is pointless

Comment: `Double(stringValue) as! Self` ??? Btw if it is not `Double` what guarantee do you have that it is a `Float`. Try `Float80(123.456789).with(numberOfDecimals: 2)` //  BOOM

Comment: @LeoDabus Have you seen that the logic is around the protocol BinaryFloatingPoint ??? The idea is that you don't care if it is Float, Double, Float80 ... as! Self is just to help the compiler ... In addition, try to see what happens when you cast floats and doubles on edge cases

Comment: This is wrong. What you need is to return a generic type using a generic method. If you want to return Self you should return the same type which is calling the method. You are not helping the compiler you are affirming that it is a Float but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Btw I am not endorsing the conversion to string to manipulate your floating point but if you want to convert a string to binary floating point you need to constrain `Self` to `LosslessStringConvertible`. Note that it will not cover `CGFloat` because it does NOT conform to it.

Comment: And it would return an optional `Self?`