# Swift encodes double 0.1 to JSON as 0.10000000000000001

Tags: json, swift, type-conversion, precision, swifty-json

After having a double variable initialized with 0.1 value and encoding it to JSON via SwiftyJSON I receive 0.10000000000000001 in JSON structure.

I'm aware of precision memory storage differences between float/double and integer but still I didn't found a quick fix for such situation besides using sprintf formatting like %.2f - I don't want to result with putting a string into json structure.

Any quick & easy solution to this will be appreciated.

I expect to have 0.1 value in JSON.
If double value is 10 I expect value 10 in JSON.
But how to avoid such precision-rounding errors during json encoding operation?

Comment: 0.10000000000000001 ***is*** 0.1. It's not Swift that does this, it's the fact that the two numbers are identical.

Comment: I have realized this and I understand that from the computing point of view it is indeed the same. But still I want to avoid such situation because of visual manners. Both platforms (iOS & Android) are saving 0.1 value into JSON. But in reality Android saves 0.1 but iOS saves 0.10000000000000001. I would like to remove this distinction

Comment: That's floating point numbers, that's how they work. You can always truncate that number to a specific digit if you want.

Comment: Truncation will not help me here. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946499/how-to-truncate-decimals-to-x-places-in-swift#comment79033256_35946921

Comment: What about formatting and storing it as a string instead?

Comment: As I wrote in the question: storing as string is a no-go for my case. Another system which parses this JSON expects a number.

Comment: Use `NSNumber` or `Decimal` instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036978/5850840 this may be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Late to the party but for others with the same issue - defining your fields as `Decimal` instead of `Float` or `Double` is the way to go.

If you're working with Floats or Doubles in your app just use e.g.:

```
let obj = MyObj(myField: Decimal(myFloat))
```

Then when you serialise MyObj to JSON you should see:

```
{
  "myfield": 0.1
}
```

instead of 0.10000000000000001