# How to obtain precision of two numbers after the decimal point but without rounding the double in SWIFT

Tags: swift

I am new with swift and I need help. I want to get first two digits after the decimal point, for example -

```
1456.456214 -> 1456.45 
35629.940812 -> 35629.94
```

without rounding the double to next one.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
let num1 : Double = 1456.456214
let num2 : Double = 35629.940812

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.roundingMode = .down        
let str = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num1))
let str2 = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num2))

print(str)
print(str2)
```

Output

```
1456.45
35629.94
```

Comment: This rounds the values

Answer (score 0):

To keep it a double you can do

```
let result = Double(Int(value * 100)) / 100.0
```

or, as @vacawama pointed out, use `floor` instead

```
let result = floor(value * 100) / 100
```

Comment: or use `floor`: `let result = floor(value * 100) / 100`

Answer (score -2):

```
extension Double {
func truncate(places : Int)-> Double
{
    return Double(floor(pow(10.0, Double(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Double(places)))
}
```

}

and use this like as;

```
let ex: Double = 35629.940812
print(ex.truncate(places: 2)) //35629.94

let ex1: Double = 1456.456214
print(ex1.truncate(places: 2)) //1456.45
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946921/1630618), especially one from the linked duplicate question.