# iOS Swift - Convert double to String precision last value rounded to next value

Tags: swift, string, double

Example value : 3.00035358. i am trying to convert double value to string

Method 1:

```
let num = NSNumber(value:self)
let formatter : NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 4
let str = formatter.string(from: num)!
return str
```

method2 :

```
extension Double {

    var stringWithoutZeroFraction: String {
        return truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(d: "%.0f", self) : String(format:"%.4f", self)
    }
}
```

expecting output to be 3.003 but getting like 3.004. i do want my last digit to be rounded to next digit.how to fix tho issue.any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to truncate decimals to x places in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946499/how-to-truncate-decimals-to-x-places-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `NumberFormatter`, you need to set the `roundingMode` to `.floor` to achieve truncating. Also, if you want to truncate, you probably want to set `maximumFractionDigits` instead of `minimumFractionDigits`.

```
extension Double {
    var string: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
        formatter.roundingMode = .floor
        return formatter.string(for: self) ?? description
    }
}

3.00035358.string // "3.0003"
```