# Check if a Double value is of a certain format with Regex

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift3

I have been trying to write a function that validates if a given Double is a number between 1-100. And only whole numbers, so something like 1.5 would not be allowed. Allowed would be 1,2,3,...,100. I'm using the following regex for that ->

```
"^([1-9][0-9]?$)|^100$"
```

however, even if i input 100, my function never gives me back true. In which way is my regex wrong?

this is the rest of my code

```
func validate(input: Double) -> Bool {

        let regex = "^([1-9][0-9]?$)|^100$"

        let inputTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
        return inputTest.evaluate(with: String(input)) 
}
```

the input has to be a Double.

Comment: Why are you using regex and a predicate for this? Convert the string to a `Double`. If that succeeds, then check the value of the `Double`.

Comment: BTW - why `Double`? Sounds like you only want integers. `3.14` is a double between 1 and 100.

Comment: And clarify what `input` is.

Comment: I have just updated the question :)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31396301/1971013) What you're doing is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex or a predicate. Simply do some basic checking as follows:

```
func validate(input: Double) -> Bool {
    return input >= 1 && input <= 100 && round(input) == input;
}
```