# Get value after decimal point from double variable

Tags: swift, double

Is there a way to get the value after the decimal point out of a double variable?

```
doubleVar = 234.045
```

Can i get only the .045 out of the variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865

Comment: `let fraction = modf(doubleVar).1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the double by 1 using [truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885641-truncatingremainder) and get the reminder.

```
var doubleVar = 234.045
var new = doubleVar.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0)
let rounded = Double(round(1000*new)/1000)
print(rounded)
```

---

**OR**

**Using C function [modf](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/02/05/how-to-split-doubles-and-floats-into-whole-numbers-and-fractions-in-swift/)**

```
var doubleVar = 234.045
let splitPi = modf(doubleVar)
splitPi.0 // 324.0
splitPi.1 // 0.045
```

Comment: This assumes the number of fractional digits will always have 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

I don't know swift but integer truncation should help. Something like

let doubleVar = 234.045

let result = doubleVar - Int(doubleVar)