# Best practice to operate on integers with floating point values?

Tags: swift, math, floating-point, integer, swift4

Often I have to use floating point numbers with integers. For example:

```
var percent:Float = 0.6347
var wholeValue:Int = 10

var result = Int(Float(wholeValue) * percent)
```

I have to convert the integer `wholeValue` to a `Float`, apply the operation, then convert the results back to `Int`. This is really clunky and tedious. Is there a better way to operate on Ints with Floats?

Comment: Yeah, I just want it to trunc, otherwise I would use ceil. But, it is just an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to implement your own custom operators, here is a simple example where I have created an operator `**` that is used to multiply and Int and a Double and return an Int

```
infix operator **: MultiplicationPrecedence

extension Int {
    static func ** (left: Int, right: Double) -> Int {
        Int(Double(left) * right)
    }

    static func ** (left: Double, right: Int) -> Int {
        Int(Double(right) * left)
    }
}
```

Example

```
let x = 4 + 10 ** 4.5 - 3.4 ** 2 // x = 43
```

For more info see the Operator chapter in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID418)

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics and create template functions that accept any type. You can then create a case for each accepted parameter using typeof:

see the swift language guide link for more details and implementation. Youll want to scroll to generic functions but read the entire page/section.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html