# How do you truncate unneeded floating point precision in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a calculator app. When I press the `%` button on the calculator, it multiplies the current value by 0.01.

If I do `52 * 0.01`, I'll get `0.52`. But if I press it again, it will calculate `0.52 * 0.01`, and I get `0.005200000000000001`.

This value gets displayed to the user of the app. How do I truncate the extra numbers to end up with `0.0052` so that it makes more sense?

Comment: Use `Decimal` instead of `Double`

Comment: That's the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `Decimal` instead of `Double` or `Float`.

Make sure the calculation is done between Decimals too, meaning you shouldn't try to do a calculation between two Doubles, and cast the result to a Decimal.

Comment: Besides using Decimal type you need to make sure to only use its string initializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let formatterUpperBreakPoint = 999999999.9
let formatterLowerBreakPoint = 0.000000001
let maxInput = 9

let decimalFormatter = NumberFormatter()
decimalFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
decimalFormatter.groupingSeparator = ","
decimalFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = maxInput
decimalFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits = maxInput + 1

let number = 0.005200000000000001

if abs(number) < formatterUpperBreakPoint && abs(number) > formatterLowerBreakPoint {
    print(decimalFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) ?? "0") // result 0.0052
}
```

Comment: OP has no idea how many fraction digits the result might be

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using double for a calculator app

Comment: @LeoDabus, I edited my previous answer, Thanks for guide.

Comment: No need to instantiate a `NSNumber` obkject. You can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)`

Comment: Btw `Decimal` would support a much broader precision. It uses 20 bytes instead of 8 and it doesn't suffer from the same issues as the FloatingPoint types. Just make sure to always use its string initializer. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865