# How to separate integral part and fractional part in Swift? An how to transform fractional part into Int

Tags: swift, integer, double

I separated fractional part, but now I need to make that part as `Int`.

For example:

> `0.5 -> 5`
> `0.63 -> 63`

---

```
let a1 = 2.5
let a2 = 7.63
let a3 = 8.81
let a4 = 99.0
let a1Frac = a1.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
let a2Frac = a2.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
let a3Frac = a3.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
let a4Frac = a4.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use Swift `Decimal` type if you would like to preserve your fractional digits precision. Second to get its fraction value you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010456/2303865). Once you have your decimal fractions all you need is to get their significand value:

```
extension Decimal {
    func rounded(_ roundingMode: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode = .bankers) -> Decimal {
        var result = Decimal()
        var number = self
        NSDecimalRound(&result, &number, 0, roundingMode)
        return result
    }
    var whole: Decimal { self < 0 ? rounded(.up) : rounded(.down) }
    var fraction: Decimal { self - whole }
}
```

---

```
let a1 = Decimal(string: "2.5")!
let a2 = Decimal(string: "7.63")!
let a3 = Decimal(string: "8.81")!
let a4 = Decimal(string: "99")!

let a1Frac = a1.fraction  // 0.5
let a2Frac = a2.fraction  // 0.63
let a3Frac = a3.fraction  // 0.81
let a4Frac = a4.fraction  // 0

let a1significand = a1Frac.significand  // 5
let a2significand = a2Frac.significand  // 63
let a3significand = a3Frac.significand  // 81
let a4significand = a4Frac.significand  // 0
```

---

If you need to convert your `Decimal` values to `Int` you can simply cast it to `NSDecimalNumber` and get its `intValue` or add those extensions to your project to add the same `NSDecimalNumber` functionality to Swift `Decimal` type:

```
extension Decimal {
    var decimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber { self as NSDecimalNumber}
    var intValue: Int { decimalNumber.intValue }
}
```

---

```
a1significand.intValue  // 5
a2significand.intValue  // 63
a3significand.intValue  // 81
a4significand.intValue  // 0
```