# How do I remove ".0" from a Double when printing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Below is my code.. I am doing 5 + 2 and I would like the output to be 7 but I am getting 7.0.  Can someone please help me and tell me why

```
var runningNumber:Double = 5
var currentValue:Double = 2
var total:Double = Double(runningNumber + currentValue)
print(total)
```

Comment: Assuming you also want to be able to do some floating point math, you probably just want to determine if the number is a [whole] integer and if so, display it as such. This should get you on your way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396301/getting-the-decimal-part-of-a-double-in-swift

Comment: The formatting of the output of `print` is unimportant, as it is not user-facing. You should worry only about the strings that the user _sees_.

Comment: Is this for a little script/tool/utility, or an end user application (where localization correctness is critical)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `.formatted()` to format the floating point number properly for you:

```swift
import Foundation

  ⋮
  ⋮
  ⋮

print(total.formatted())
```

Comment: this does not work if you have, for example:
 `var runningNumber: Double = 5.1` and
 `var currentValue: Double = 2.3`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine If `total` is 7.4, I would assume you want to print it like `"7.4"` instead of `"7"`

Comment: only `SwiftResearcher` can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

you could just do this:

```
 print(String(format:"%0.0f", total))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Int`s instead of `Double`s

```
let two = 2
let five = 5
print(two + five)
```

- Cast to `Int` when printing

```
let two: Double = 2
let five: Double = 5
print(Int(two + five))
```

- Format to a string with zero fraction digits

```
let two: Double = 2
let five: Double = 5
print(String(format: "%.0f", two + five))
```

- Use `NumberFormatter`

```
let two: Double = 2
let five: Double = 5

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

let sum = NSNumber(value: two + five)
print(formatter.string(from: sum)!)
```

Comment: For the `NumberFormatter`, consider using `.formatted()` instead. You can use `.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))` or `.formatted(.number.rounded(increment: 1))` to specify the precision if needed.

Comment: ah https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/3816389-formatted this is new api since ios 15. i didn't know that

Answer (score -2):

I got it working but changing the code to this

```
import UIKit

var runningNumber:Double = 5.3
var currentValue:Double = 2
var total:String =  NSNumber(value: runningNumber + currentValue).stringValue

print(total)
```

Comment: that does not work, you then have to make `var total:String = ...`

Comment: sorry about that.. you are right